# Our app on Force.com should now support Turkish, any ideas how to approach it?

Tags: force.com

Our app should support another language (Turkish).

What is the best way to integrate this language in our app?

Should we write conditional code in visual force which renders different language text based on the locale? Can it be done differently? How do we translate tab names? side bar etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever your visualforce has hardcoded english text ,you will need to replace with custom labels .Custom labels can then be translated using translation workbench .

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_translations.htm

As seen from above docs ,Turkish is supported as End User Language .Only your admin and online help is not translated and rest all of the labels can be translated .

You can read about Translation workbench as below documented

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm&language=nl

Be careful when translating some comparison operators if hardcoded in visualforce as rendering condition .

Comment: I wonder, should I create a Custom Label for every language? For example, the word "Hello" should be defined twice in CustomLabel for Turkish and CustomLabel for English?